# Confusion with differential equations

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

We have the following ODE: $ \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{x}{y}$

If we want to solve it we just rewrite this to the form: $ydy = xdx$ and we then take the integral, but here is where I get confused. My textbook says this is the integral:

$\dfrac{y^2}{2} + C_1 = \dfrac{x^2}{2} + C_2 $, but isn't the integral of dx just x and the integral of dy just y? Where are these left out?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is clearer than the "differentials" manipulation. You can write your equation as

$$y'=\frac x y$$ or $$y'y=x$$

This is really

$$y'(x)y(x)=x$$

Upon integration we get that

$$\frac 1 2 y(x)^2=\frac{x^2}2+C$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't done integrals in a while, so I'm rusty. But why isn't the integral of $y'y$ equal to $\dfrac{1}{2}y^2 \times y = \dfrac{1}{2}y^3 $?

Comment: Take the derivative with respect to $x$ of $\frac 1 2 y(x)^3$. What do you get? Is it $y(x)\times y'(x)$? Take the derivative of $\frac 1 2 y(x)^2$ with respct to $x$. What do you get? Remember the chain rule. Being rusty with these integrals is equivalent to being rusty with derivatives.

Comment: Yes, I see I made a mistake, but I don't see where exactly the $y'$ goes when integrated. Because I know the derivative of $\dfrac{1}{2}y^2$ is just $y$.

Comment: @YlykCoitus The derivative of $\frac{1}{2}y^{2}$ with respect to $y$ is $y \frac{dy}{dx}=yy'$. Remember the chain rule.

Comment: @YlykCoitus Sorry, that's a typo. It should say 'with respect to $x$'

Comment: @DanielLittlewood Ok, I understand. But normally, if you're asked to find the derivative of $\dfrac{1}{2}y^2$ (I've never seen 'with respect to .. added') you'd give the answer $y$. So, is the fundamental part here the 'with respect to y'?

Comment: @YlykCoitus The $dx$ in $dy/dx$ means 'with respect to $x$'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you are integrating $y\ dy$ and $x\ dx$, not $dy$ and $dx$.

Answer (score 0):

the integral of $ x \ \ dx$ is $\frac{1}{2} x^2+c$